# \n not working in the output

Tags: python, newline, spacing

Hi I currently have an output of:

> 'root:$6$aYGtvxKp/bl6Fv2y$sdZ3FbdJYQlP8VcfFZT.Y67We5EQmqcHW4I9Gl/3pXp8v4.nu9qMIEkmOcdRuD0lBTvEtnMHosEo7OEaYgG4E0::0:99999:7:::\nbin:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\ndaemon:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nadm:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nlp:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nsync:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nshutdown:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nhalt:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nmail:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\noperator:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\ngames:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nftp:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nnobody:*:17110:0:99999:7:::\nsystemd-bus-proxy:!!:17572::::::\nsystemd-network:!!:17572::::::\ndbus:!!:17572::::::\npolkitd:!!:17572::::::\ntss:!!:17572::::::\nsshd:!!:17572::::::\npostfix:!!:17572::::::\nchrony:!!:17572::::::\funky:$1$EgZiG263$4W/wMljYzhOqnupg9cJ7W/:17599:0:99999:7:::\n'

From my code:

```
command = "cat /etc/shadow "
process = os.popen(command)
results = str(process.read())
```

I'm trying to make it look like the one in the command prompt wherein it is in a table form but for some reason when I transfer it to python it does do the new line function "\n" does not work. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you do `print(results)`, or something different? Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve].

Comment: You appear to be looking at the `repr()` of the string, wherein newlines will be shows as escape sequences, as will unprintable characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just read the file directly:

```
filename = '/etc/shadow'
with open(filename) as shadowfile:
    content = shadowfile.read()
    # or possibly lines = shadowfile.readlines()
```

Did you try printing the output or did you just see the contents of the results variable in the interpreter? In the latter case, the line breaks will be shown as \p, while print(results) will produce the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = 'root:$6$aYGtvxKp/bl6Fv2y$sdZ3FbdJYQlP8VcfFZT.Y67We5EQmqcHW4I9Gl/3pXp8v4.nu9qMIEkmOcdRuD0lBTvEtnMHosEo7OEaYgG4E0::0:99999:7:::\nbin::17110:0:99999:7:::\ndaemon::17110:0:99999:7:::\nadm::17110:0:99999:7:::\nlp::17110:0:99999:7:::\nsync::17110:0:99999:7:::\nshutdown::17110:0:99999:7:::\nhalt::17110:0:99999:7:::\nmail::17110:0:99999:7:::\noperator::17110:0:99999:7:::\ngames::17110:0:99999:7:::\nftp::17110:0:99999:7:::\nnobody::17110:0:99999:7:::\nsystemd-bus-proxy:!!:17572::::::\nsystemd-network:!!:17572::::::\ndbus:!!:17572::::::\npolkitd:!!:17572::::::\ntss:!!:17572::::::\nsshd:!!:17572::::::\npostfix:!!:17572::::::\nchrony:!!:17572::::::\funky:$1$EgZiG263$4W/wMljYzhOqnupg9cJ7W/:17599:0:99999:7:::\n'
for i in l.split('\n'):
 print(i)
```

Output:

```
root:$6$aYGtvxKp/bl6Fv2y$sdZ3FbdJYQlP8VcfFZT.Y67We5EQmqcHW4I9Gl/3pXp8v4.nu9qMIEkmOcdRuD0lBTvEtnMHosEo7OEaYgG4E0::0:99999:7:::
bin::17110:0:99999:7:::
daemon::17110:0:99999:7:::
adm::17110:0:99999:7:::
lp::17110:0:99999:7:::
sync::17110:0:99999:7:::
shutdown::17110:0:99999:7:::
halt::17110:0:99999:7:::
mail::17110:0:99999:7:::
operator::17110:0:99999:7:::
games::17110:0:99999:7:::
ftp::17110:0:99999:7:::
nobody::17110:0:99999:7:::
systemd-bus-proxy:!!:17572::::::
systemd-network:!!:17572::::::
dbus:!!:17572::::::
polkitd:!!:17572::::::
tss:!!:17572::::::
sshd:!!:17572::::::
postfix:!!:17572::::::
chrony:!!:17572::::::    unky:$1$EgZiG263$4W/wMljYzhOqnupg9cJ7W/:17599:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. print(l) will yield the exact same results (on a system that respects Unix line breaks).

Comment: I agree with @MartinSandChristensen. `print(l)` is already enough.